# Undefined reference to `TextOutW@20' with Gdi32.lib linked

Tags: c++, linker

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664792/undefined-reference-to-textouta20) asks about "undefined reference" problems with code for windows. Apparently the solution was to link `gdi32.lib`.

I have `gdi32.lib` linked and still get that error:

```
14:26:24 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SomeWindows ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\SomeWindows.o" "..\\src\\SomeWindows.cpp" 
g++ -o SomeWindows.exe "src\\SomeWindows.o" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\Lib\\winv6.3\\um\\x64\\Gdi32.Lib" 
src\SomeWindows.o: In function `Z7WndProcP6HWND__jjl@16':
C:\Users\Mxx\eclipse-workspace\SomeWindows\Debug/../src/SomeWindows.cpp:78: undefined reference to `TextOutW@20'
collect2.exe: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück

14:26:26 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.139ms)
```

I'm trying to create Window's example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx, this is my code:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
     HWND hwnd,
     UINT uMsg,
     WPARAM wParam,
     LPARAM lParam);


static TCHAR a[] = _T("My first C++ program");
static TCHAR b[] = _T("My first wstring");

int main () {

    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = a;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
       a,
       b,
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
       CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
       500, 100,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       hInstance,
       NULL
    );

    ShowWindow(hWnd,3);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
       TranslateMessage(&msg);
       DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;


}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("I just write stuff here.");
    switch (message)
       {
       case WM_PAINT:
          hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

          // Here your application is laid out.
          // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows Desktop!"
          // in the top left corner.
          TextOut(hdc,
             5, 5,
             greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
          // End application-specific layout section.

          EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
          break;
       case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          break;
       default:
          return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
          break;
       }
    return 0;
}
```

The source of the error is to some degree obvious. TextOut(...) is defined as TextOutW(...), which is declared by `wingdi.h`. But how do I even go about finding out where the implementation should be? (From the answer to the other question, I assume that's gdi32.lib) And how do I even find out what's wrong? (And what does the @20 mean in the error message?)

I use Win 8.1 (and Win 8.1 SDK), Eclipse CPP IDE and MingW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdi32.lib`, and other *.lib files in Windows SDK, work with Visual Studio.

Use `lgdi32` instead of `gdi32.lib` to use these libraries with gcc.

You can also use MinGW library instead. The corresponding library files have `'lib'` prefix and `*.a` extension:

```
gdi32.lib -> c:\MinGW\lib\libgdi32.a
```

Also note, you need `-mwindows` compiler flag for Windows programs (if you don't want to see a console window)

Example:

```
g++ -Wall file.cpp -mwindows c:\MinGW\lib\libgdi32.a -o app.exe    
//or
g++ -Wall file.cpp -mwindows -lgdi32 -o app.exe
```

Comment: `-lgdi32` should work (without needing to specify the full path to library), if MinGW(-w64) is installed correctly

Comment: Thanks, that was precisely it! Would you know about the @20-suffix? It's in the MingW library apparently, but how did TextOutW ever get redefined as TextOutW@20?

Comment: I am not sure about @20 suffix. `TextOutW` is a DLL import, maybe it has something to do with "compiler name mangling", the compiler adds @20 - By the way, you are making a 32-bit program, and `...\\x64\\Gdi32.Lib` is 64-bit, not that you want to use those files anyway.